# Eclipse Java exception example

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

This program is for exception handling, but the problem point is at **UserException**????

```
import org.omg.CORBA.UserException;

    public class Ch9_3_3 {

    class UserException extends Exception {
        int data;
        public UserException(int d) { data = d; }
        public String getMessage() {
            return ("Error! You negotiate too much for auction price: " + data);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                if (i==3) throw new UserException(3);
                System.out.println("No. of auction: " + i);
            }
        }
        catch ( UserException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception note: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Exception reason: ");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        finally { System.out.println("Error handling completed."); }
        System.out.println("End of program!");
    }

}
```

With error message:
*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
No enclosing instance of type Ch9_3_3 is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Ch9_3_3 (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Ch9_3_3).
at Ch9_3_3.main(Ch9_3_3.java:16)*

Note: Line 16 is `try {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a compilation error in your code below

```
 if (i==3) throw new UserException(3);
```

You can't create an instance of an inner class like this.
Instead you can either

make the inner class static. since you calling it from the main class.

```
public static class UserException extends Exception
```

or can make the object as below

```
if (i==3) throw new Ch9_3_3().new UserException(3);
```

Comment: The program can be run now, but it's strange, result is as below.
_Exception reason: 
Error handling completed.
Ch9_3_3$UserException: Error! You negotiate too much for auction price: 3
 at Ch9_3_3.main(Ch9_3_3.java:16)_

Comment: That's what you program for. Whats strange in it?